# How do you get the groupUniqueId for the Google Group Settings API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-api-python-client, google-groups-settings

I am looking at this API: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/groups-settings/v1/reference/groups/get

However, when I try the test at the bottom, it always returns 400 Bad request. I have tried using the Google group email address (without the @gmail.com and with the @gmail.com) for several groups I am in.

How do you find the groupUniqueId for a Google group?

Comment: The uniqueId should be `group-name@example.com` where example.com is the Google Apps domain for your company.

Comment: Did you find an answer for this question  ?

Answer (score -1):

I had the problem yesterday and 'think' I undertood it:
I use the PHP SDK and had to use groupssettings API.
When I executed my query, the PHP answer was something such: "incorrect json format".
Still in my API, I had to FORCE the JSON to be used, by adding optional parameter: alt=json
Then, The query worked.
Until now, this is the only Google API where I had to specify this.
What I suspect is the "Try It" feature to use json, and because the API does NOT returns json by default, it just fails. Too bad there is no way to force json there.